# Tastypie - get user groups resource_uri

Tags: python, django, api, rest, tastypie

I'm trying to update the groups assigned to users via an API (via rest) with Tastypie.

I tried passing the group id's directly in, however it says that the URL provided is not a valid resource. I then tried passing in a URL such as '`/api/v1/groups/1/`' but that is saying that's not a link to a valid resource.

Any hints? I'm creating user records just fine from a standard django view/form, but I would like to do this as a REST action.

Comment: Have you created `ModelResource` classes for `groups` and registered them with the API?  You might want to show some code.  You can visit the `/api/v1/?format=json` page to see which resources are available through the API.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the basics (sometimes they can be overlooked). I created the Group Resource but never got around to adding it to urls. That got everything working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to specify the format, such as:  `/api/v1/groups/1/?format=json` ?

Comment: No, that is only if you are accessing it with a web browser.